# Concatenate two meta keys?

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a school timetable as a custom post type. Each post is a school class with a post meta box containing two text fields for specifying the hour and minute that a class starts in 24-hour time format:

```
_start_hour
_start_minute
```

I am trying to output the posts in order according to time e.g.

```
    // the args
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'my-cpt',
    'meta_key' => '???????',
    'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
    'order' => 'ASC',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
);

// The Query
$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );

    while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post();

            // ordered output according to time

           endwhile;
```

In 'meta_key' is there some way I can concatenate the two meta keys?

I have tried `'meta_key' => '_start_hour' && '_start_minute'` but this breaks the query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately no, wordpress doesn't support this feature, you will have to sort it by yourself after fetching it from the database and before the loop.

*Disclaimer note*
This is extremely ugly by design, but this is Wordpress so you have to play with what you get, you can make it less ugly if you fallback to writing the SQL queries yourself, depends on performance in my opinion, as Wordpress can be a performance degrader beast if not handled properly you should consider making it with SQL queries instead.

```
// Fetch all posts - (1 SQL Query)
$query = new WP_Query(array(
    'post_type' => 'my-cpt',
    'order' => 'ASC',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
));

foreach ($query->posts as &$post) { // N queries as the number of posts you have - totally inefficient 
 $post->meta = get_post_meta($post->ID);
}

usort($query->posts, function($a, $b) {
   $a_time = strtotime($a->meta['_start_hour'][0] . ':' . $a->meta['_start_minute'][0]);
   $b_time = strtotime($b->meta['_start_hour'][0] . ':' . $b->meta['_start_minute'][0]);
   if ($a_time > $b_time)
      return 1;
   else if ($a_time < $b_time)
      return -1;
   else
      return 0;
}); // Sorting by date

... the_loop ...
```

note that this is totally untested so it should just give you pointers on hour should you do it, and again I say, you should refactor this to join the meta keys in advance, that way you can perhaps already sort it with the SQL instead of the PHP...